# matplotlib draw ellipse contour

Tags: matplotlib, contour, ellipse

I am trying to draw something similar:
[image]

The main idea is to draw ellipses with different color in some specific range, for example from [-6, 6].

I have understood that `plt.contour` function can be used. But I do not understand how to generate lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally wouldn't do this with contour as you then need to add information about the elevation which I don't think you want?

`matplotlib` has `Ellipse` which is a subclass of `Artist`. The following example adds a single ellipse to a plot.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
ellipse = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy=(0, 0), width=2.0, height=1.0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.gca().add_artist(ellipse)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
```

[image]

You then need to research how to get the effect you are looking for, I would [have a read of the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse) in general making things transparent is done through `alpha`.